# Asserting exceptions in async delegates

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, nunit

I'm using NUnit 3. I wrote an extension method:

```
public static T ShouldThrow<T>(this TestDelegate del) where T : Exception {
  return Assert.Throws(typeof(T), del) as T;
}
```

Which allows me to do this:

```
TestDelegate del = () => foo.doSomething(null);
del.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
```

Now I want something similar for async:

```
AsyncTestDelegate del = async () => await foo.doSomething(null);
del.ShouldThrowAsync<ArgumentNullException>();
```

So I wrote this:

```
public static async Task<T> ShouldThrowAsync<T>(this AsyncTestDelegate del) where T : Exception {
  return (await Assert.ThrowsAsync(typeof(T), del)) as T;
}
```

But that doesn't work: `'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [`Assert.ThrowsAsync`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.ThrowsAsync) doesn't return a `Task`, and cannot be awaited. Remove `await` from your extension method.

```
public static T ShouldThrowAsync<T>(this AsyncTestDelegate del) where T : Exception {
  return Assert.ThrowsAsync(typeof(T), del) as T;
}
```

Example usage from the [docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.ThrowsAsync). Note that `Assert.ThrowsAsync` returns a `MyException` and that the `await` is in the delegate.

```
[TestFixture]
public class UsingReturnValue
{
  [Test]
  public async Task TestException()
  {
    MyException ex = Assert.ThrowsAsync<MyException>(async () => await MethodThatThrows());

    Assert.That( ex.Message, Is.EqualTo( "message" ) );
    Assert.That( ex.MyParam, Is.EqualTo( 42 ) ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I automatically assumed that because it was a delegate, that the assertion needed to be awaited... doh!

Comment: Based on MS naming convention it should have been. ;)